# Magento 2.0 and AWS SES SMTP

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, smtp, magento-2.0

I'm trying to get a new `Magento 2.0` installation to send email through my `AWS SES` SMTP server.  I can send email from the linux command line on the server but I can't find any documentation on how to get Magento to send emails.  [This](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-server) is
 all the documentation I can find but it doesn't give detail.  It just talks about Magento needing an email server.  This is from the link

> Blockquote
>   Set up an e-mail server
>   Magento requires an e-mail server. We don’t recommend a particular server but you can try any of the following:
>
> •Postfix for CentOS (digitalocean tutorial, CentOS documentation)
>
> •Postfix for Ubuntu (digitalocean tutorial, Ubuntu documentation)

This isn't much to go on, has anyone set this up with `Magento 2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it directly with Magento2, but you can use extensions like https://marketplace.magento.com/opsway-module-amazonses.html